# How to insert multiple data into database?

Tags: c#, sql

i would like to insert multiple data into my database. I am using for-each statement to get the data and when i insert into the database, it generates 10(just a random no. depending on the no. of data i retrieved) rows for me with one data in every row instead of all in one row. here is the for-each statement i am using.

```
 foreach(var kiev in dict)
    {
        string na = kiev.Key;
        if(na != "db_table_name")
        {
            string quer = "insert into " + HttpContext.Current.Session["tablename"].ToString() + " ( " + kiev.Key + " ) VALUES ( '" + kiev.Value + "' ) ";
            SqlCommand cl = new SqlCommand(quer, con);
            cl.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: whats the problem u r facing here?

Comment: use parameters not string concatenation for your sql query.

Comment: when i insert the data, lets say 10 data, it will create 10 rows in my database with one data in every row

Comment: You have to combine `INSERT` and `UPDATE` sql statements, because `INSERT` will insert new row each time it executes.

Comment: @DarjanBogdan i have no plans of updating it. I just wanna insert everything in all at once

Comment: Use SqlBulkCopy for one time to save multiple records in your table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are better options like "SqlBulkCopy" available as already mentioned in the comments but also something like this should work:

```
string tablename = "";
string values = "";
string keys = "";

foreach(var kiev in dict)
   {
        string na = kiev.Key;
        if(na != "db_table_name")
        {
                keys += kiev.Key + ", ";
                values += "'" + kiev.Value + "', ";
        }
   }
keys = keys.Remove(keys.Length - 2);
values = values.Remove(values.Length - 2);

string quer = "insert into " + HttpContext.Current.Session["tablename"].ToString() + " ( " + keys + " ) VALUES ( " + values + " ) ";

SqlCommand cl = new SqlCommand(quer, con);
cl.ExecuteNonQuery();
```